# Translating a shape 3 times: What is a smarter way to code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code outputs a "C" shaped polyomino translated twice as shwon in the figure below. As can be seen from the code, I have written the same description for the polyomino 3 times. What I would much rather have is a code which functions as follows:

Give a name, say "pattern" to the C-shaped polyomino once it has been described.

Now if I want to display the polyomino at a certain position, I should just be able to tell the code the x and y coordinates of the two points where the bottom-left endpoint of the polyomino sits and the code should put it there.

Basically I want a more modular way to write the same code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % For testing with "framed" option to look at the bounding box
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[hatched/.style = {pattern=north west lines, opacity=0.3}, scale=4]
        \begin{scope}
            \draw[line width=0.2cm] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
            \fill[red] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, yshift=3cm]
            \draw[line width=0.2cm] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
            \fill[red] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, yshift=6cm]
            \draw[line width=0.2cm] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
            \fill[red] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as supplement to @JpuleV answer:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       % it load tikz too
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,   % it is very old, now is available 1.16 ... upgrade it!
             ticks=none}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, % For testing with "framed" option to look at the bounding box
                calc,
                patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm,fill=red] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic {myc} (1,3) pic {myc} (2,6) pic {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm,fill=red] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic {myc} (1,3) pic {myc} (2,6) pic {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=4, transform shape]
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
    \draw[line width=2mm,fill=red, xscale=-1] (0, 0) -| (2, 1) -| (1, 2) -| (2, 3) -| cycle;
        }
}
\path (0,0) pic {myc} (-1,3) pic[xscale=-1] {myc} (2,6) pic {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
If you like to rotate for 180 degrees all shapes, than simply add scale=-1 to `myc` style definition. IN case that you like to mirroring only one of them, than add `xscale-1` to `pic`: `pic[xscale=-1] {myc}`. however, reflecting pic`reflect its internal coordinates. this you can simple compensate with accordingly changed`x` coordinate of pic position. see third example in above image.

Comment: Your diagram looks better then mine. In my diagram there is a problem at the overlaps. The boundaries do not gel well. What did you do to not have this problem?

Comment: (i) i use `\draw[line width=2mm,fill=red] ...`, consequently fill is inside lines, (ii) the same you obtain if you first draw `\fill` and than lines with `\draw`. with this `fill` not overlaps lines, consequently overlap of lines is seen differently (less disturbing).

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing. Suppose I define myc/.pic as you have which gives me the c-shaped polyomino. Suppose now I wanted the mirror reflection of this c-shaped polyomino (equivalently, 180 rotation). Is there a way to define myc2/.pic by using the rotation operation? In other words, I want to do something like myc2/.pic = rotate by 180{myc/.pic }. Thanks.

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 9):

Reference: `pgfmanual.pdf`, section 18.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    myc/.pic={
        \draw[line width=0.2cm] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
        \fill[red] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 2) -- (2, 3) -- (0, 3) -- cycle;
    }
}
\path (0,0) pic {myc} (1,3) pic {myc} (2,6) pic {myc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: MWE  in the question use for image `scale=4` which in your solution doesn't work on the same way (`pic` are not scaled). You should mentioned, that in case of scaling image, now is needed to add `transform shape`.

Comment: Nice! To compress the code even more, you could fuse the `draw` and `fill` part with `\draw[line width=0.2cm,fill=red]`! :)

Comment: @Vinzza It is already in Zarko's answer, so maybe I should not edit my answer.